# Dapper - passing getdate as parameter

Tags: dapper

i am using SQL Dapper and i want to pass parameter like **DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()) + 1, -1)** from UI. how can i do this?

DynamicParameter takes key as string and value as object and i am passing the key as the parameter i specified in the query and value as the expressing that i get from ui and here is the error what i get **Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.**

--Need Help.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't entirely clear to me which bit you want to send as a parameter, since:

```
 DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()) + 1, -1)
```

is **not** a parameter. Ultimately, you could bake that directly into the SQL, although you might want to whack it in a variable:

```
declare @when datetime = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()) + 1, -1);
-- some more sql here, at some point using @when
```

If you want to pass in just a date as a parameter, then perform the date code first:

```
DateTime when = // some C# here...
var data = conn.Query<Whatever>(sql, new { when, ... }).ToList();
```

It is never possibly to directly pass in a complex statement (such as `DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()) + 1, -1)`) as a single typed parameter. In normal usage, a parameter of type (say) `datetime` is given a single value, typically from a computed `DateTime`.